# How to use Grafana alerts for auto remedy

Tags: graphite, grafana, collectd

I have configured Grafana to display system metrics using `collectd`. I have also configured slack alerts using custom policies on grafana. Is it possible to use these alerts to trigger a script/service for auto remedy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the alert notification types is a custom webhook. It sends a [JSON document with the alert notification details](http://docs.grafana.org/alerting/notifications/#webhook) to a custom endpoint that you can define yourself:

[image]

Comment: This works for me, documentation for grafana is not friendly at all.

Comment: @AtmeshMishra if something is missing or confusing, please open an issue on GitHub - or even better send a PR with friendlier documentation for this feature :-)

Comment: I used the webhook, it sends ruleURL in JSON body. Where should I change it? Should I change in grafana.ini ??

Comment: It is based on the domain setting in the ini file: http://docs.grafana.org/alerting/notifications/#configure-the-link-back-to-grafana-from-alert-notifications

Comment: I changed domain and root_url setting in grafana.ini. It is still showing http://localhost:3000.

Comment: Did you restart Grafana after changing the ini?

Comment: Yes, I did restart server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144384/discussion-between-daniel-lee-and-atmesh-mishra).